# How to refresh DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to force DataGrid to refresh its content on a form closing event. I have tried various methods, searched this forum for answers but still I am unable to find a solution.

This is how my DataGridView is being populated :

```
string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ST"].ConnectionString.ToString();
string strSQL = "SQL QUERY";
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
dataAdapter.Fill(table);
bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

I have tried the Invalidate method, BindingSource.ResetBindings but still the GridView doesn't refresh. How do I force refresh it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Data refresh

I think you are talking about data refresh. In this case you can just *rebind* your `DatagridView` to the source:

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
dataGridView1.DataSource = aDataSource;

//Update Data in aDataSource
//...

dataGridView1 = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = aDataSource;
```

In your code snapshot `aDataSource` should actually be `bindingSource1`. As @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN mentioned, in your case you should enclose the re-binding inside the proper callback to attach it to the right event:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){ ... }
```

#### Data refresh

If you don't want to rebind your source you can adopt another solution: binding your `dataGridView1` to a Collection *Observable*. In this case, it will be enough to implement the *[INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)* interface to notify the change to its listeners (your `DataGridView` component)

### Graphic refresh

If you are searching only for a graphic refresh, there is a specific method:

```
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated. Could you please clarify that what should be the newSrc?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer to avoid some confusion (as there is no need to introduce new variables). `aDataSource` should be the `bindingSource1` after you properly updated it.

Comment: Have a look at `GetData` in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I think it does exaclty what you need. The trick is, again, to rebind the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and change this line:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
```

to

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Comment: sorry bro, but that doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doing it similar to this way helps?

```
public DataTable GetData(string SQLQuery)
{
   string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ST"].ConnectionString.ToString();
   string strSQL = "SQL QUERY";
   SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
   SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
   dataAdapter.Fill(table);
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   //Maybe only one of the clear code works.
   dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = null; 

   BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
   bindingSource1.DataSource = GetData("SQL QUERY");
   dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
   dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; //<-----------Try taking this off aswell
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
}
```